# How to properly write a setup.py script for pydev project with mulitple packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, py2exe

I've got a pydev project (i'm using eclipse as an ide) and my project has a number of packages, the structure is as follows

```
+top_level_app
|
-+app_package 
|
|-----+database_pkg
|     |
|     -init.py
|     -insert_db.py
|     -read_db.py 
|
|-----+parser_pkg
|     |
|     -init.py
|     -my_parser_1.py
|     -my_parser_2.py
|
|-----+resources pkg 
|     |
|     -my database.sqlite
|     -my_logtile.test
|     -my_icon.ico 
|
|-main.py
|-setup.py
```

Now it runs fine from the ide, but I need to create a windows executable (I am using py2exe) the setup.py is meant to be used to create a fully self contained executable, python interpreter and all bundled in.

My application makes use of a number of libraries such as jinja2,matplotlib, [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/)
I also have a sqlite database and some icons that are resources, i.e when the application runs it connects to the sqlite database to do stuff
The path to all these resources is quite important as they must all exist in the release folder created by py2exe.

So far when I try to import app_package in my setup.py I get

- "Module Import error app_package not found"

This is wierd as it runs fine from eclipse, also how do I make sure resources are available in the right location when the release folder is created?

Essentially with this "nice" project layout how do I maintain all the elements when I try and create an executalbe that will run on someone else's machine, without any external dependencies?